# Compute angle from vertical at which a sphere strikes the lip of a cup

Tags: math, geometry, projection

I'm working on a problem, wherein a sphere of known radius is dropped vertically and strikes the edge of a cup.  I need to figure out the angle of deflection, which will be a function of where along the sphere contact occurs.  I.e., if the contact point is dead-center (the pole), the angle of deflection is 0.  The further from the pole that contact is made, the larger the deflection angle.

In the formulation of the entire problem (this is just part of it), I'm strictly using the projection onto the x-y plane, so the only information I have is about the projected circles.  I know the location of the center of the ball-circle and cup-circle, their radii, and the size of the (downward projected) overlap.

I can compute the angle of deflection, if I only have the length of the chord from the pole to the contact point.  How can I get the length of this chord, working from the x-y projection givens?  The attached image shows some of how the problem is formulated.

[image: problem summary]

Comment: I'm wondering if [math.se] would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I think there is enough information to compute everything. Find the contact point, find it on the sphere, do some algebra.

Comment: Oops, you are correct about the posting.  I didn't realize that was a separate domain.  Thanks, I'll post there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer duplicated from my correct repost on math.stackexchange.com

> Thank you very much to my friend Dr. Andrew McHugh for helping me see the solution. I overlooked that I can compute the angle theta by knowing the horizontal distance (X) from the lip of the cup to the ball's vertical axis. Theta is then the arcsin of the ratio of X to the radius (r). In the x-y plane projection, X is the radius - the line connecting the cusps of the overlapping lenticular area (d). Hence, theta = arcsin((r-d)/r).